# ASP.NET MVC PartialView with List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, partial-views

I am at my first MVC project. I want to create a page with a header and in this header to be placed a partial view with category list.

This is what I did so far:
I created the master page (_Home.cshtml). Than in Shared folder I created a View (Category.cshtml). See my picture.
[image]

My Category.cshtml content:

```
@model IEnumerable<ArtSchool.Models.Category>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Visible)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Visible)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

My master page file:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>_Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    @Html.Partial("ASCX/Header")

    @Html.Partial("Category")

    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

When I run the project I got the error:

[image]

I know that is a newbie question but it's my first MVC project.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass a `Model` with this call `@Html.Partial("Category")`. You should call a Controller/Action in which this model gets generated and then return the partial.

Comment: what have you done in your actions?? you should render partial view in your controller

Comment: Are you sure? In my project I have nothing more he showed. I'm not passing any additional data,calling controler,returning partial and everything works

Comment: @szpic, is your partial view strongly typed? If so, then any reference to the `Model` will yield the same error.

Comment: @AndreiV Yes. In my vs strongly typed is default. There is no checkbox create strongly Typed etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interpret those partials as some static sections inside your HTML, then I would suggest you to call `Html.Action()` which returns your partials:

```
@Html.Action("GetPageHeader","Home")
@Html.Action("GetPageCategories","Home")
```

HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPageHeader()
{
   return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/_PageHeader.cshtml");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPageCategories()
{
   var categories = databaseContext.GetAllCategories(); //Get your categs
   return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/_Categories.cshtml",categories);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1**

If you want to use partial view you need to pass model to this helper this way

```
@Html.Partial("Category", CategoryModel)
```

before you pass this model you have to fill it with some data.

**Solution 2**

also you can use @Html.Action() Method with name of ActionResult method which will return partial view for you.

for example:

```
  @Html.Action("GetCategories", "ControllerName")

  public ActionResult GetCategories() {
    // fill some data for your model here
    return PartialView("Category", model);
  }
```